# What are the dirty things that come out when you erase a mark called?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

You use a sharpener to sharpen a pencil and you have wood shavings.

Now, you use an eraser to erase a mark on a paper and you have some dirty bits.

What are these bits called?

Are they called dirt?

For example, "*dirt got all over the table when you erased text.*"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Eraser crumbs* is about as popular as *[eraser dust](https://www.bobvila.com/articles/best-eraser/)* or *eraser shavings*.   *[Eraser bits](https://www.thearchitecturalstudent.com/2012/08/hand-drafting-tutorial.html)*, *eraser rubbings*, and *[eraser residue](https://papercanyon.com/types-of-erasers-a-comprehensive-guide/)* are less common.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eraser+dust%2Ceraser+crumbs%2Ceraser+shavings%2Ceraser+residue%2Ceraser+rubbings%2Ceraser+bits&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=1

The English Language and Usage site has also answered [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/434201).

Comment: Could be a transatlantic thing but in AmE when you use a lead pencil eraser you get eraser crumbs. I've never heard "dust" used of those particles, only of the dust that can be clapped out of a felt chalkboard eraser.

Comment: And _eraser rubbings_ (the word I would instinctively use – though in context I’d just call it _rubbings_) is somewhere between _eraser shavings_ and _eraser crumbs_ in popularity, it seems. I can’t find a dictionary that mentions it specifically, but to me, anything that has been rubbed off a surface is a ‘rubbing’, whether it’s with an eraser or something else; this is just one subtype.

Answer (score 4):

We could consider *eraser dust*.  A search with this phrase gives us a list of products like eraser dust vacuum, eraser dust cleaner and so on.  This shows that the phrase is quite established.

Comment: but "dust" sounds like tiny particle like powder, but the dirty bits I mentioned are quite big as big as a sand or a rice?

Comment: [sawdust](https://images.app.goo.gl/aHR2L5p78g8CZhFM6) can be quite coarse too, but it is still called dust.

Comment: that doesn't look like sawdust, sawdust is much finer like powder, https://worldexport.com.vn/pine-wood-sawdust-pine-sawdust-use-for-cultivation

Comment: "A _grain of_ sand or rice".

Comment: @Tom The image in Seowjooheng’s image is absolutely sawdust. It’s the first image used on the [Wikipedia article for ‘sawdust’](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawdust).

Answer (score 3):

The word "debris" will do for just about any kind of unwanted multiple solid bits or chunks, of just about any size from microscopic to large boulders.

[Here](https://www.tomboweurope.com/en/products/eraser) is an advertisement where they refer to "eraser debris".

Of course there is also the transatlantic "rubber" vs. "eraser" divide, with the latter term being preferred in AmE since there "rubber" more often refers to a condom.